STM32F103RB: using cap designing in power supply
I'm currently designing hardware using STM32F103 MCU. I'm reading AN2586 and NUCLEO-F103RB schematic as reference.
I'm designing the power supply now, and AN2586 says to connected to use 100 nF caps for each Vdd pin and one 10 µF cap.

The pic below is what I have done so far

and when I look at NUCLEO-F103RB schematic to check if I've done right, I only find 4× 100 nF cap, no 10 µF cap.

Is there any specific reason for no 10 µF cap? Why is there no 10 µF cap in the schematic?

If the power supply has a bulk capcitor nearby it may serve the purpose of the 4.7uF-1ouF capacitor

You are correct; there is no such 10uF capacitor on VDD on the board.
However the VDD supply comes from an onboard regulator very near the MCU and it is bypassed with 1uF ceramic capacitor.
So the reason is that the power delivery network is either proven or assumed to be adequate without specifically adding a 10uF capacitor.
The 10uF capacitor requirement, as proven by the statement of either tantalum or ceramic, is just a generic blanket statement how you should design your board power delivery network without further knowledge of from where the MCU supply comes and the quality it or how long cables there are.
And sometimes the reason is just standards. For an USB powered product, 10uF capacitance is maximum allowed to be directly plugged in. So if you are making an USB powered product, the inrush energy (not current itself but energy) may be too high if you simply put too much capacitors everywhere.

Thank you for explaining :D. Is the 1uF capacitor you said near the regulator C18 on NUCLEO-F103RB SCHEMATIC?

Physically large capacitors have higher parasitic inductance and resistance.
Also, higher grade ceramics and higher capacitance can increase the cost. So a lot of times you will see 2-3 capacitors with different capacitance and difference sizes/ceramics to achieve the desired capacitance and reduce the parasitic elements and improve the overall performance of the capacitor circuit at higher frequencies.
